# Problem when running PowerShell

Tags: search, powershell

I've a PowerShell script file to create results source. It works well on staging, but has some problems on UAT. First of all is the trouble with **Get-SPSite**. I've managed to resolve it. However, when I was trying running **Get-SPEnterpriseSearchResutlItemType**,

It threw an error: *Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation*.

I couldn't found more information other than that error.

I then tried going to Search Result Sources in Site Settings and encounter error. From log,

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/manageresultsources.aspx, Error=There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator.
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.SearchObjectDatabaseException: There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator.
>   Getting Error Message for Exception 
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.SearchObjectDatabaseException: There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator.

Can you narrow where the problem is?

Comment: are you administrator of the search service?

Comment: Are you running elevated?

Comment: @Nk SP, Matthew: We now only have problem when accessing Search Setting in general, like Search Result Sources or Search Result Types. The log only tells me "there was an exception in the Database" as posted above. Please advise.